# Encountering error: /qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online.run: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I downloaded at x86-2.0.5-2 (32 bit) online installer from quote website. After downloading I changed the permission of the executable and run the quote-unified-Linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online. I am running it using a terminal.  I am getting error bars: ./Qt-unified-Linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online. run: No such file or directory.  I am using Ubuntu x86_64 machine.  What could be the cause of this error.  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the space in the name

Comment: The error that is printed is misleading. Your issue is that your Ubuntu version cannot run this 32-bit binary. Download the 64-bit installer instead.

Comment: I want build 32 bit and 64 bit executable using qt in Ubuntu how could i do it